# UITableViewCell label text not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, iboutlet

I have one question regarding UITableViewCell.
I have base class inheriting from UITableViewCell.
In that class I have this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
```

Then I have several cells inheriting from that base class created using xib files.

Now I am adding new cell but in this case I am doing it programatically. My problem is that when I try to set the text for that new cell like this:

```
[self.name setText:@"My Label"];
```

Text is not displayed.

How can I fix this?

Thanks and regards

Comment: What is your code for adding this new cell?

Comment: Is cell displayed ?

Comment: Could you print `self.name`? Is it nil? What's its frame? Is it missing Autolayout?

Comment: does attach the cell label with`@property`?

Comment: Cell is displayed because if I do self.textLabel.text = item.name; it works.
How do I attach cell label? It is created in base class

Comment: I have tried to set frame but it does not work

Comment: You need to debug. For that, is `self.name` `nil`? Whats its frame? Do you use Autolayout? Is it of the correct class in the xib? `Then I have several cells inheriting from that base class created using xib files.` Did you do that part propertly? How do you init them? `registerNib:`?